# Why is class field callable in one class method but not callable in another?

Tags: python

I have a class which looks like that:

```
class Sha3_224():
  def __init__(self):
    self.keccak = keccak.Keccak_f(b = 1600)
    self.sponge = sponge.Sponge(f = self.keccak, pad = sha3_hash_byte_padding, r = 1600 - 2*224, d = 224)
    self.digest = bytearray(0)

  def process(self, fd):
    fd.seek(0, 2)
    message = msg.Message(l = fd.tell(), fd = fd)
    fd.seek(0, 0)

    del(self.digest[0:len(self.digest)])
    self.sponge.process(msg = message, out = self.digest)

    print(self.digest)
    print(len(self.digest))

  def digest():
    print(self.digest)
```

When I instantiate an object I can call its `process` method without problem but when I try to call its `digest` method I get

> TypeError: 'bytearray' object is not callable

I can also `print(self.digest)` in `__init__` without error.

Can anyone indicate me a reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

There is no `digest` method any more. You have overridden it with the `digest` attribute. There is only one namespace.

A short example:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 1
    def attr(self):
        pass

t = test()
t.attr        # 1
t.attr()      # TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
test.attr     # <unbound method test.attr>
test.attr(t)  # works
```

Comment: well actually the `digest` method still exists, but can only be looked up on the class...

Comment: It is obvious, what a shame of mine -.- .

Answer (score 1):

The `digest` instance attribute (set in `__init__`) shadows the `digest` method. You'll have to rename either the instance attribute or the method.